# Hadoop distcp copy from on prem to gcp strange behavior

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hdfs, gsutil, distcp

when I user distcp command as

```
hadoop distcp /a/b/c/d  gs:/gcp-bucket/a/b/c/ , where d is a folder on HDFS containing subfolders.
```

If folder c is already there on gcp then it copies d ( and its subfolders)  from HDFS to gcp inside c but if c folder is not there on gcp then it creates c folder on gcp and copies subfolders of d (but not d it self ) inside of c folder of gcp.

So if e is the sub folder in d on HDFS and folder c exists on gcp then the  out put of following command :

```
hadoop distcp /a/b/c/d  gs:/gcp-bucket/a/b/c/
```

will be

```
gs://a/b/c/d
```

If e is the sub folder in d on HDFS and folder c does not exist on gcp then the  out put of following command

```
hadoop distcp /a/b/c/d  gs:/gcp-bucket/a/b/c/
```

will be
`gs://a/b/c/e`

why is the out put of second command not same as out put of first command ? both commands are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no subdirectories on Cloud Storage. Instead there is a flat namespace where all the objects are hosted.

The hierarchichal view that one sees is due to the `gsutil` tool that makes naming work the way users would expect. So when one copies a file name `your-file` to the target `gs://[BUCKET]/path/to/target/` the Cloud Storage service interprets this as a file named `gs://[BUCKET]/path/to/target/your-file`.

In your case when "folder c" doesn't exist and you try to copy under this "subdirectory", the first time that you will run this command, the following object will be created:

```
gs://a/b/c/e
```

If "folder c" exists, then "folder d" and all its contents(including `d` itself) will be copied under `subdirectory c`

Your observation:

> If folder c is already there on gcp then it copies d ( and its
> subfolders) from HDFS to gcp inside c but if c folder is not there on
> gcp then it creates c folder on gcp and copies subfolders of d (but
> not d it self ) inside of c folder of gcp.

is totally right and this behavior is expected.

You may find more details regarding the rules that are applied and how subdirectories work in the [Cloud Storage documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork#overview)